# Implementing Z Buffer Algorithm

Tags: c++, graphics, 3d, rendering, zbuffer

I'm trying to experiment with computer graphics and would like to implement Z Buffer algorithm for rendering in Software.

So I'm trying to use the following plane equation:

```
z = -(ax + by + d)/c
```

To compute the Z coordinate of a pixel using the plane form equation
should I compute the Face normal of the triangle ? or a normal of a vertex is enough ?

Here is how I compute it:

```
double zValueOfPoint(float vx, float vy, float vz, float x, float y, float nx, float ny, float nz)
{
    float A = nx;
    float B = ny;
    float C = nz;
    float D = -(nx*vx, +ny * vy + nz * vz);
    float z = -(A*x + B * y + D) / C;
    return z;
}
```

vx,vy,vz vertex,  x,y pixel coordinate, nx,ny,nz normal of a vertex

Now for each TOP or Bottom Triangle I check the Z Pixel to ZBuffer pixel

```
// Top of the triangle
    for (int y = y0; y<y2; y++)
    {

        for (int x = xl_edge; x<xr_edge; x++)
        {
            float zOfPixel = zValueOfPoint(vx, vy, vz, x, y, nx, ny, nz);
            if (zOfPixel < zbuffer[int(x + y * m_Width)]) {
                zbuffer[int(x + y*m_Width)] = zOfPixel;
                SetPixel((unsigned int)x, (unsigned int)y, color);
            }

        }//end for loop x
```

The same for bottom triangle

Right now I get completely broken model. The Z Buffer is initialized correctly.

[image: 3]

Comment: `float D = -(nx*vx, +ny * vy + nz * vz)` has an extra comma in the middle. Also, once you have implemented perspective interpolation in your rasterizer, this comes for free.

Comment: `z` is interpolated from the face vertexes directly the same way as `x,y` ... while rasterizing. No need to use plane equation...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do anything with face normals when implementing Z buffering. You only need *per vertex "depths"* for your projected triangles.

Further, and I apologise for only skimming through your question's code, but if you want to do a *perspective* projection, then make sure the "depth" you are linearly interpolating per pixel is *not* the world/camera depth but something that is proportional *(What? No mathjax on SO?)* to 1/Z_world or 1/W.

That is, you have a projected triangle where each vertex, *Vi*, has
 *{Vi_screenX, Vi_screenY, Vi_projectedDepth}* and
 
   *Vi_projectedDepth = linear_function_of(1 / Vi_Z_camera)*.

Very simple examples include:

> Vi_projectedDepth = 1/Vi_Z_camera *or*
>   Vi_projectedDepth = 1.0 - 1/Vi_Z_camera

You must then linearly interpolate the Vi_projectedDepth  values across the triangle but you *don't* need to take the reciprocal of these interpolated values ( *at least not for Z-buffer ordering. If you want to do perspective correct texturing, OTOH, you _may_ need to eventually compute the reciprocal* ).

If you don't do this, you can get very strange results whenever geometry has implicit intersection - I just remembered I made a comment on this in [SE Graphics](https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/a/8022/209).